# dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm using a third-party library that has some custom view implementations. In the implementation, they call `Utils.showSoftKeyboard(context as Activity)`. This, along with using the fragment as an @AndroidEntryPoint causes the following exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`.

Is there any way to fix this without altering the third-party library?

Answer (score 13):

If the third-party library has an issue tracker, it's a good idea to raise an issue about this.  There is no guarantee that the `context` of a `View` is an `Activity`: the same problem can be caused just as easily by an `android:theme` attribute in the custom view or any ancestor.

If you don't inflate any `@AndroidEntryPoint` views in your fragment, you can work around this by getting a `LayoutInflater` directly from the activity context.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val baseInflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireActivity()) // NOT context
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Without Hilt Dependencies we can access parent activity as below

(context as ContextWrapper).baseContext

Answer (score 4):

It might be late for your problem but here's a solution which might help others having the same problem.
You basically should check the context type before trying to cast it.

```
  val mContext = if (context is ViewComponentManager.FragmentContextWrapper)
            context.baseContext
        else
            context
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460392/8940448) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Nitrodon, I found the solution.  I was using Hilt with view bindings and my code looked like:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentGoalsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

I had to do:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val baseInflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireActivity())
    _binding = FragmentGoalsBinding.inflate(baseInflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

I was also inflating my viewModel with a viewModel Provider and that was a crash (no init<> method),  and I then used `by viewModels()`.  Voila!  The code ran