# Fragment with @AndroidEntryPoint provides different LocalContext

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have this code

```kotlin
class AddReminderFragment : BaseComposeFragment() {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        // this is null when i add @AndroidEntryPoint to this fragment
        val activity = LocalContext.current as? ComponentActivity
    }
}
```

`BaseComposeFragment` is just a little helper i'm using and it looks like that:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseComposeFragment : Fragment() {

    @Composable
    abstract fun Content()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                this@BaseComposeFragment.Content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to get `ComponentActivity` like that `val activity = LocalContext.current as? ComponentActivity` and it's working fine until i add `@AndroidEntryPoint` to `AddReminderFragment`. When i do that the `LocalContext.current` have different value: `ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper` which cannot be cast to `ComponentActivity` giving me null instead of activity.

Why is that happening and how can i prevent that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get activity in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675386/how-to-get-activity-in-compose)

Comment: Well this gives me a way to bypass that, but since the issue i'm having is due to library that asserts that it have to be `CompatActivity` then this won't really solve my issue. And also i'd like to know why adding entry point annotation changes value here

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64342511/3585796)

Answer (score 1):

```
= ComposeView(requireContext()).apply
```

Use requireActivity() here instead of requireContext()